# Find $f(x)$ if $f(x+1) = x^2-5x+3$.

Tags: calculus

The question also came with a Hint: Let $u = x+1$ and find $f(u)$.

Ok so I have tried to apply the hint, which is

$f(u) = u^2-5u+3$, or $f(u) = (x+1)^2-5(x+1)+3$.

$f(u) = x^2-3x-1$.

Other than this I'm not really sure how I can proceed, or what the hint implies when it asks me to find $f(u)$. Could I somehow derive $f(x)$ from $f(u)$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(x)=f((x-1)+1)$, so replace $x$ by $x-1$ on the right hand side

Comment: thank you @Fakemistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's use the hint.

Let $u = x+1$

Then $f(x+1) = f(u) = x^2-5x+3 = (u-1)^2 - 5(u-1) + 3 = u^2-7u + 9$

So we just got that:

$$ f(u) =    u^2-7u + 9$$

But the variable name doesn't matter (it can be $u$, $x$, $t$, etc.), this does not change the function itself... So we can now replace the variable $u$ with $x$ and we get:

$$ f(x) =    x^2 - 7x + 9$$

Comment: hi and thanks @peter.petrov i understood your explanation. it seems that I was supposed to express $u - 1 = x$. I understood that $f(x) = f((x-1)+1)$ but somehow this extra variable $u$ just confused me, lol

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $f(x+1) = x^2-5x+3 = (x+1)^2 - 7(x +1) + 9$

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $x-1$for $x$, since $u=x+1\implies x=u-1$

$f(x)=(x-1)^2-5(x-1)+3=x^2-7x+9$

Answer (score 0):

From
$$f(x+1)=x^2-5x+3=(x-2.5)^2-3.25=((x+1)-3.5)^2-3.25$$
observe
$$f(x)=(x-3.5)^2-3.25=x^2-7x+9$$